# nhibernate hql subquery : convert null to zero

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I am trying to update sum of particular amount from one table as a value in another table, but getting problem when the particular id does not exist in another table :

the hql i have looks like beow:

```
        var session = SessionManager.GetCurrentSession();
        var queryString = string.Empty;

        queryString += @"update CLiner cl set cl.UnbilledDue = 
            (select sum(cu.UnbilledAmount) as UnbilledAmount from CUnbilled cu 
                      where cu.AccountNo = cl.AccountNo and cu.FileDate = :fileDate) 
        where cl.FileDate = :fileDate ";

        var query = session.CreateQuery(queryString);
        query.SetDateTime("fileDate", new DateTime(2014, 10, 7));
        query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

but its giving exception when the particular account no does not exist in child table and the sum is returned as zero.

i tried changing the subquery select to

```
        select isnull(sum(cu.UnbilledAmount),0) as UnbilledAmount
```

which as expected is not supported by nhibernate hql. so there a way i can convert null to zero in hql select statement...

Comment: try with: coalesce(sum(cu.UnbilledAccount), 0)

Comment: great thanks.. it worked.. can you please put it as answer.

Comment: Dear, ok, I'll convert in answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
coalesce(sum(cu.UnbilledAccount), 0)
```

Reason:
Normally when you wirte a SQL query to prevent NULL you must apply an `ISNULL` function over the `SELECT`, in this way:

```
ISNULL(SELECT sum(...., 0) or COALESCE(SELECT sum(...., 0) (return the same result but COALESCE can applied with more parameter, ISNULL has only two parameters)
```

but in HQL isn't possible, so you can use `COALESCE` function to prevent that behaviour.